# DELETE * FROM TABLE WHERE this=that not working

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm not sure why this query isn't working!  This query is to delete the user's account:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE * FROM users WHERE cookie='$cookie'");
```

HOWEVER, when I replace `DELETE` with `SELECT`, it works!  Is my `DELETE` syntax wrong?

Comment: You should read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html). You will find proper syntax described in different ways. There are even examples!

Comment: @Terminus thank you for the advice! Looking forward to using that documentation next time :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need the * when using `DELETE`. Just do

```
"DELETE FROM users WHERE cookie='$cookie'"
```

Comment: That was a really lazy mistake of me, thanks for that quick tip! ^_^

Comment: @ConnectionCoder No problem, happy to help! If this solved your problem, I'd really appreciate it if you accepted it as an answer.

Comment: I'm about to do that, but the system won't allow me to accept an answer for another 8 minutes because of the really short amount of time I got an answer.  I will accept the solution though!

Comment: @ConnectionCoder Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you use `SELECT *`, it works because you are selecting all columns from the table. In your case, your query should look like this

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE cookie='$cookie'
```

since the columns do not need to be specified here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have `*` in a DELETE statement.

If you want to delete all rows, this will do:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM users WHERE cookie='$cookie'");
```

When you use `SELECT * FROM`, `*` would select everything. However for DELETE, it isn't needed as you can only delete the whole row.